# Access key value pair in nested dictionary list

Tags: dictionary, robotframework

I am learning robot frameworks and trying to work with dictionaries. following is my dictionary list. If I have to access 'rowId': 'DF-1' from the record, how do I do it?

```
${record}=     {'findItems': [{'rowId': 'DF-1', 'colId': 'CF-1'}]}
```

I tried ${record}[0][0] or ${record}['findItems][0] but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Short answer - `${record}['findItems'][0]['rowId']` will return you that key's value, DF-1, as long as the variable is properly defined as a dictionary. I would suggest reading on accessing list and dictionary members in python, the basics - it'll cover even you'll need to work with them in RF.

Comment: Your code sample isn't valid robot, assuming the code you posted is part of a test or keyword. If it's in the variable table, it's setting `${record}` to a string, not a dictionary.